# How to cut a rectangle sheet into half?

Tags: math, geometry, logic

We have rectangle sheet, and a small rectangle piece cut inside it at RANDOM place. How to make make that sheet into exact same 2 halves?

Comment: Seems like subset sum problem.

Comment: Are you sure it's always possible? E.g. when the original rectangle is 3x2, and a 2x1 piece is cut at the top left corner.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask this question on http://math.stackexchange.com.  This doesn't seem like a programming problem.

Comment: That's an easy one! Cut it so that you end up with 2 sheets of half the original thickness :) My point: we need **a lot more information**. Can there only be straight cuts, or can cuts be curved as well? Is there a limit on the amount of cuts you can make? Exactly the same, meaning not only the same *area*, but also the same *shape*? Can they be mirror images (which are NOT equal)? Do you also want the most cost-effective way of doing it? Or do you also want the maximum possible combined length of the cuts?...see my point?

Comment: All, it should single cut. those 2 should similar halves. Not cutting on thickness. Cut should be single cut.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you do a cut through the center of a rectangle, no matter at what angle, this rectangle will be divided in half.

Thus, if we make a cut through the center of the cutout rectangle, each side of the cut will have 50% of the cutout area. And if we -- at the same time -- cut through the center of the large rectangle, this should do it. Both sides of the cut have half the area of the large rectangle, minus half the size of the cutout.

[image]

Of course, that is if by "exact same 2 halves" you mean *same area*, but not necessarily *same shape*. The latter will generally not be possible.

Comment: +1 for a simple and elegant approach.

Comment: @tobias_k :) In simple words, draw a straight line passing through the centers of both rectangles.. which definitely cuts into half. I am confident the latter(Similar shapes) also possible. Brilliant solution.. Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of thought, I think this is the correct answer.

We have to fold the paper sheet, many times, so that it should form the rectangle of the small rectangle area.

If we cut the folded one, it should give 2 equal parts definitely.

Answer (score 0):

re: folding - will not work because you could easily end up with more than two parts cutting folded rectangle.

I would try brute-force approach. If the hole is co-oriented to large rectangle, you can cut along one of the edges and have only three cases to check: 1 try to cut above the hole - if it's not possible to end with same area halves, try to 2 cut through the hole - if it's still not possible, 3 cut below the hole will certainly do it. the code for 1 and 3 would be very similar, btw. all 3 cases are simple linear equations for the height of cut. For example, 1:

```
+----W---+
d        |
+--------+
|        |
|  +-w-+ |
H  h   | |
|  +---+ |
|        |
|        | 
+--------+
```

We have d * W = (H - d) * W - h * w

If d from this equation is not above the hole, go to case 2, and so on.